# Prevent original template being applied in inherited control

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, styles

I am having an issue in an application where I would like to derive my own custom control from a control included in a commercial library (scichart).

I am overriding OnApplyTemplate, as in the below code, but am running into an issue where when calling `GetAndAssertTemplateChild` (A function in the library that is pretty much the same as `GetTemplateChild` but throws and error if the result is equal to null) the part cannot be found in the template.

While investigating this issue I found that OnApplyTemplate is being called multiple times, it is first called with the template of the control being inherited from, and is then recalled with the template of the new control. Is there any way to avoid this and to never apply the base classes template.

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    base.OnApplyTemplate();

    AnnotationRoot = GetAndAssertTemplateChild<Grid>("PART_LineAnnotationRoot");
    _line = GetAndAssertTemplateChild<Line>("PART_Line");
    _ghostLine = GetAndAssertTemplateChild<Line>("PART_GhostLine");
    _label = GetAndAssertTemplateChild<TextBlock>("PART_Label");
}
```

Comment: I think you might be able to use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411962/wpf-styling-a-generic-base-control. But, it seems like a lot of trouble to me. Why not just use `GetTemplateChild()`, check for a `null` result, and skip the rest of the method if it's `null`? It will be plenty obvious if the part goes missing in your own template. If you're really that worried about it, you can always validate your custom template elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to avoid this and to never apply the base classes template

If you only want to call the derived class' `OnApplyTemplate()` method, you should avoid calling the base class' method in the overridden method:

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    //DON't CALL THIS ONE: base.OnApplyTemplate();

    AnnotationRoot = GetAndAssertTemplateChild<Grid>("PART_LineAnnotationRoot");
    _line = GetAndAssertTemplateChild<Line>("PART_Line");
    _ghostLine = GetAndAssertTemplateChild<Line>("PART_GhostLine");
    _label = GetAndAssertTemplateChild<TextBlock>("PART_Label");
}
```

And if you want to provide your own default custom `ControlTemplate` from scratch, you should define a static constructor in your control class:

```
static YourControl()
{
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(YourControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(YourControl)));
}
```

...and define the default template in a `ResourceDictionary` called "generic.xaml" located in a folder called "Themes" at the root folder of the project in which the control class is defined.

Comment: I had already tried that method of overriding the style and the effect was the same.